# javascript var limit, value not exceeding 127

Tags: javascript

I am facing a strange issue in the below javascript code. From a page, the values which are getting pushed in project_list array are project_id (value range from 1 to 150) and bid_amount (value range from 1 to 2000). Everything works fine apart from one thing, whenever value of project_id (sent from page) is greater than 127, the value getting inserted in code line `project_id = project_list[i];` is 127. As I checked, var does not have such a low limit. Also this code line `bid_amount = parseFloat($("#bidAmount_"+project_list[i]).val());` works fine, easily taking value greater than 127. Please help, I have not declared shortint anywhere!

```
function bid_project_tournament(current_round)
{
    var i;
    var project_list= [];
    $('#B2WProjectList :checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
        project_list.push($(this).val());
    });

    $("#bid_project").attr("disabled","disabled");
    var project_id;
    var bid_amount;
    var bid_data="0";
    for(i=0;i<project_list.length;i++)
    {
        project_id = project_list[i];
        bid_amount = parseFloat($("#bidAmount_"+project_list[i]).val());
        bid_data = bid_data+";"+project_id+","+bid_amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is actually happening?

Comment: It looks like you're building the `project_list` array from a series of checkboxes. Don't checkboxes have either the value `checked` or blank?

Comment: Like @Pointy, I'm curious as to how you're checking the value. Are you sure it's not being converted to a byte data type in your back end code or database? Have you checked the POST request using e.g. Chrome's web inspector or Firebug, or ran a JS debugger and added a watch expression?

Comment: actually the above is a long code ... which is passing value further to save it in database .... for all project_id greater than 127, the value which is getting saved in database is 127

Comment: JLRishe Sir, you are bang on. Please suggest way out .... whichever checkbox is checked, its corresponding value is getting passed

Comment: @AakashGoel Could you check the column definition in your database and make sure it's (e.g.) `INT` and not `BYTE` or `TINYINT`? Also the type of the variable being used in your back end code?

Comment: Or make it `unsigned`...

Comment: the checkbox html on page is <input type="checkbox" id="project_checkbox" value="<?php echo $project_id; ?>" /> ... so the checkbox does has a value ... cant it take value more than 127?

Comment: @JLRishe I think jQuery's `val` returns the value of the checkbox's `value` attribute rather than `checked`?

Comment: @AakashGoel Yes, it can. Could you look at the generated source for the checkboxes and maybe add it to your answer or a JS sandbox like jsFiddle/JS Bin?

Comment: @Jordan Gray the code on page for generating source for checkboxes is fine .... in fact we are also printing that number of page, all that is fine ............ in another javascript function, i tried to check value of checkbox getting passed; in that it does take value more than 127! so, issue seems to be in above code

Comment: @Jordan Gray to check i used the below code - function check_bidInput(this_obj)
{
 if(this_obj.checked == true)
 {
  var project_id = this_obj.value;
  if(project_id>=128)
  {
   ui_alert("128+!",'non-error');
   this_obj.checked = false;
  } } }

Comment: @Jordan Gray you were right. I resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: @AakashGoel Oh, sorry, I completely missed this! What turned out to be the issue, a database or back-end code problem?

Comment: @JordanGray tinyint in database .... a really dim-wit thought sometime back made me assign datatype as tinyint; didnt occur to me max value would be 127, just because tinyint width in database is 4 and i thought it could take 4 digits easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out the reason for this specific problem in the comments (a column with the type `TINYINT` instead of `INT`), but I'll leave a more general answer in case people come here with similar problems.

If you find that numbers are being capped at or around some power of two when sent to the server, there's a good chance the problem lies somewhere in your back-end code or database. Here are some things to check:

- Have you accidentally set a column in your database to `BYTE`, `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT` or similar instead of `INT` or larger? Check your column definitions!
- Are you passing the value to a variable in your back-end code which has a type like `short`, `word`, `byte` or similar?
- If the values are in pre-filled HTML form fields, have you checked if the values in that HTML are correct?
- If everything above checks out, fire up your browser's debug tools and watch the network activity panel to confirm if the values are being capped on the client.

There's no (reasonable) limit to the value of a checkbox in HTML, or indeed to any field without any restriction like a `max` or `maxlength` attribute. The biggest number you can represent in JavaScript without losing precision is 9,007,199,254,740,992, so if your numbers are being capped or rounded above that value, the problem might be JavaScript.